# What am I doing wrong, calling a rest api

Tags: vb.net, rest, http-headers, httpclient

I am new to .Net (any help will be greatly appreciated) and I am trying to implement this class to write to a rest api. All it does is pass in some data and does a postAsJsonAsync to the service.
It was written in C# and converted to VB.net to be added into a VB.net application solution.
It works once and then fails on the second call to it, when it initialises another instance of Uri. 
 Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in System.Net.Http.dllequest."}{"This instance has already started one or more requests. Properties can only be modified before sending the first request."} 
Code here:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Net.Http.Headers

Namespace Logging
    Public Class LogMessage
        Public Property Application As String
        Public Property Area As String
        Public Property Activity As String
        Public Property Description As String
        Public Property User As String
    End Class

    Public Class ActionLogging

        Public Shared Client As New HttpClient()

        Public Shared Function AddToActionLog(Activity As String, Description As String, User As String)
            Dim message = New LogMessage() With { _
                .Activity = Activity, _
                .Description = Description, _
                .User = User, _
                .Application = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Application"), _
                .Area = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Area") _
            }

            If Run(message) IsNot Nothing
                Run(message).Wait()           
            End If   

        End Function

        Public Shared Function CreateMessage(message As LogMessage) As Uri
            Dim task = Client.PostAsJsonAsync("Action", message)
            task.Wait()
            Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = task.Result
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
            Return response.Headers.Location          
        End Function


        Public Shared Function Run(message As LogMessage) As Task
            Client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("RestAPIServer"))
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear()
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(New MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")) 

            CreateMessage(message)  

        End Function

    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: What part of the exception is unclear? What you do inside `Run()` can only be done before sending the first request.

Comment: Yes I understand the exception, I cannot work out how to setup the 'DefaultRequestHeaders' only once. The class will be called many times within the same session. The way I am doing the calls is obviously wrong, but I cannot see how to do it differently.

Comment: OK solution found. Hopefully this might help someone else in the future.

Comment: New code as follows.

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Net.Http.Headers

Namespace Logging
    Public Class LogMessage
        Public Property Application As String
        Public Property Area As String
        Public Property Activity As String
        Public Property Description As String
        Public Property User As String
    End Class

    Public Class ActionLogging

        Private ReadOnly Shared Client As New HttpClient() With {.BaseAddress = new Uri(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("RestAPIServer"))}

        public Sub New()
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear()
            Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(New MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"))       
        End Sub

        Public Shared Function AddToActionLog(activity As String, description As String, user As String)
            Dim message = New LogMessage() With { _
                .Activity = Activity, _
                .Description = Description, _
                .User = User, _
                .Application = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Application"), _
                .Area = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Area") _
            }

            SendMessage(message)

        End Function

        Private Shared Sub SendMessage(message As LogMessage)              
            Dim task = Client.PostAsJsonAsync("Action", message)
            task.Wait()
            Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = task.Result
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()            
        End Sub

    End Class
End Namespace
```